# Why r2_score is coming negative?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am implementing Linear Regression Algorithm using python.

I have below set of data in excel
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bluq.png)

When I am running below code the r2_score & intercept_ value is coming as negative. I know the negative r2 score means that prediction is worse. Can someone please guide me what I am doing wrong?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

file = pd.read_csv("heart-disease_1.csv")
X = file.drop("num", axis=1)
y = file["num"]

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.20)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
lr = LinearRegression()
# Fit the data(train the model)
lr.fit(X_train,y_train)
# Predict
y_predicted = lr.predict(X_test)

print(lr.coef_)
print(lr.intercept_)
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
print(r2_score(y_test,y_predicted))
```

output:

```
coef_: [0.02324541 0.61279124 0.02102044 0.00361862]
intercept_: -5.918421626295825
r2_score: -0.44135602407107744

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: how many datapoints do there are in total, besides the 9 in the image?

Comment: in addition to the above question, how many different values does `num` take (only three values are shown - 0, 1m and 2)?

Comment: @ Marat how many datapoints do there are in total, besides the 9 in the image?
Just for testing I have put only 9 records in file. 

@desertnaut in addition to the above question, how many different values does num take (only three values are shown - 0, 1m and 2)?                   
only 0, 1 & 2 values I have.

Comment: 1) the low number of actual points might very well be the reason of the low `r2`; use all your data 2) the 3 response values may also mean that you would be better with a classification approach (e.g. logistic regression) instead of a regression one 3) no need to repeat the questions in the comments when answering